# How to integrate Onepay Vietnam payment gateway in Android Application?

Tags: php, android, transactions, payment-gateway, payment

I am creating a Android App. In that after booking a room , he have to pay the money through online payment gateways. I implemented Paypal,braintree.

But the client requires Onepay Vietnam payment integration. Since that company based on vietnam he needs it.

**My Problem**
I searched the Onepay site . They have no `Mobile APIs`. Only `WebService` based payments.

So I downloaded a `PHP` web service and implemented it. After entering billing details , It redirects to a sandbox testing payment page.

The documentaion of Onepay provides an dummy card for testing. For unfortunately it is not working.

So I don't know how to finish testing payment.

The second problem is , the Onepay vietnam site is very poor and the documentaton is a bit confusing .

**My steps to resolve**
I tried searching many site . I cant get clear documention how to implement onepay vietnam integration .

The problems are

- The documentation don't have any reference to In APP payment
- The web site seems to be confusing and many pages only in vietnamise
- Sites that provides help to payment gateways integrations don't have Onepay vientam

**My Request**
Please help to integrate Onepay vietnam payment gateway in my mobile app please.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should contact OnePay support

Comment: Yes. I also thought about that. But before asking them , I think , I can clear my side with my efforts and stackoverflow-ians help !